# How to determine a month has past to the date using Carbon

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

A person gains a point after each month he has been on the platform. So if he joins July 3rd, on August 3rd he gets an additional point.

The start date is set in the DB as a `date` field.

When thinking about this, it seems there are different scenarios in which I could miss adding this point if I just do something like this in the daily cron:

```
$startDate = new Carbon($startDateFromDb);
$today = new Carbon( date("Y-m-d"));

if ($startDate->day === $today->day) {
    //Add point!
}
```

For example, the person starts Nov 30th. So on Dec 30th he should get +1 points (now has 1 total). On Jan 30th he should get +1 points (now has 2 total).

The problem would be in Feb, since Feb doesn't have 30 days so `$startDate->day === $today->day` would never be true this month.

This would also occur on any month with 30 days, if a person starts on a 31st.

Does Carbon have some method that would allow me to verify this, or should I just make a long if/else with current month/days per month and my own logic?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the expected output in your example? Did he get the bonus in month with 30 days?

Comment: Yes! It doesn't matter the amount of days per month. He should get it every month, on the day of the month he started.

Comment: Do not check for the same number, check if it is the last day of the month.

Comment: @Nic3500 If the user started on the 15th, he should get the point on the 15th of each month, not on the last day

Comment: What is the expected behaviour when the user starts on Nov 30th and Feb and Mar come along? Do they get a point at the end of Feb (since there is no Feb 30th) and then again on Mar 30th?

Comment: Indeed, my point is if the user starts on the last day of a month, for all the subsequent months, you will have to use that last day, and not the same number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it manually:

```
public static function shouldAddVacationDay(User $user, Carbon $today) : bool {

    $shouldAddVacation = false;

    if ($user->startdate) {

        $start = new Carbon($user->startdate);

        // Normal day
        if ($today->day === $start->day) {
            $shouldAddVacation = true;
        }

        // Add a vacation day on March 1 for users that started Jan 29,30,31.
        if ($today->month === VacationlogController::$MAR && $today->day === 1) {
            if ($today->isLeapYear() && ($start->day === 30 || $start->day === 31)) {
                $shouldAddVacation = true;
            } elseif ($start->day === 29 || $start->day === 30 || $start->day === 31) {
                $shouldAddVacation = true;
            }
        }

        // If he started on the 31st of a month where the following month has less than 31 days, add a
        // vacation day the following month on the 1st.
        if ($start->day === 31) {

            if ($today->month === VacationlogController::$MAY && $today->day === 1) {
                $shouldAddVacation = true;
            }

            if ($today->month === VacationlogController::$JUL && $today->day === 1) {
                $shouldAddVacation = true;
            }

            if ($today->month === VacationlogController::$OCT && $today->day === 1) {
                $shouldAddVacation = true;
            }

            if ($today->month === VacationlogController::$DEC && $today->day === 1) {
                $shouldAddVacation = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return $shouldAddVacation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact behavior you're looking for and what you can store in your database, there are a couple of options:

**Option 1**:
If the only thing that can adjust a person's points is tenure then it may be simplest to just calculate the points on the fly. This can be done pretty simply using Carbon's `diffInMonths`. This would look something like this:

```
$startDate = new Carbon($startDateFromDb);
$today = Carbon::today();

$points = $today->diffInMonths($startDate);
```

**Option 2**:
If  you can't use on-the-fly calculation, then the most straight forward approach is to store the tenure points in addition to the total points. This allows you to check if there's a difference between the current tenure points and the awarded tenure points:

```
$startDate = new Carbon($startDateFromDb);
$today = Carbon::today();

$calcTenurePoints = $today->diffInMonths($startDate);
if ($calcTenurePoints < $awardedTenurePoints) {
    $points += $calcTenurePoints - $awardedTenurePoints;
    $awardedTenurePoints = calcTenurePoints
}
```

You could also combine the two options by only storing the non-tenure points and calculating the tenure points on the fly. The disadvantage to doing it that way is that you can't easily get the points directly from the database.